# logintoboggan and password tab conflict

Tags: 7, users

I encountered a conflict when I tried using logintoboggan and password tab modules together.

What I wanted to was to cancel the password requirement when users sign up and set their password when they confirm email addresses.

But the issue is, set your (initial) password form does not show up when I install the password tab module.

Anyone has solution for this?